# System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, utility

I have a Asp net web site. sometimes (I don't know when) it threw an exception. (to the browser it sends 404 error).

```
The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception. 
at System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String value) 
at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HtmlEncode(String value) 
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.set_InnerText(String value) 
at Results.DefineCheckboxFilter(String filterName, String param, Boolean createHidden) in d:\HostingData\chani.poz\macher.co.il\wwwroot\App_Code\Results.cs:line 79 
at Controls_NadlanFilter.InitialFilter() in d:\HostingData\chani.poz\macher.co.il\wwwroot\Controls\NadlanFilter.ascx.cs:line 50 
at Controls_NadlanFilter.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\HostingData\chani.poz\macher.co.il\wwwroot\Controls\NadlanFilter.ascx.cs:line 31 
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)System.Web Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
```

The DefineCheckboxFilter function is in Results class. in the function line 79 (The line that threw the exception)

```
HtmlGenericControl ht = (HtmlGenericControl)ls.FindControl("HasterGale" + filterName);
ht.InnerText = "הסתר";
```

p.s. The problem occurs even if I don't in this page, and then I get the same `webutility` exception with other details. For example:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception. 
    at System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(String value) 
    at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HtmlDecode(String value) 
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessAttributes(String text, Match match, ParsedAttributeCollection& attribs, Boolean fDirective, String& duplicateAttribute) 
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) 
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)System.Web The type initializer for 'System.Net.WebUtility' threw an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at last:
The problem was because I have a website that define like webSite in visual studio (not webPage or something like that). and so I need to define in the server **not** `Intagrate PipeLine`. That all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a .NET Framework error.  It should be corrected in Hotfix rollup 2848799.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2848799